# How do `>` and `>>` work?

Tags: command-line, redirect

I tried to `rev` a file and then pipe it to `cat > same_file` but it was turning into a blank file.

While I tried `rev file.txt | cat > file2.txt && mv file.txt file2.txt;` it worked.

Even `rev file.txt | cat >> file.txt;` worked.

But when I tried `rev file.txt | cat > file.txt` it failed.

Comment: You can also leave `cat` out like this: `rev file.txt > file2.txt && mv file2.txt file.txt`. This is a *superfluous use of `cat`*. By leaving it out you spare spawning an extra process.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The basic thing you need to grasp in this case between both ways of redirecting (> and >>) is:

### >

Redirects and **overwrites** the information where it was pointed to. This happens while receiving any information through pipe "|"

### >>

Redirects and **concatenates** to the information it was pointed to. This happens while receiving any information through pipe "|"

In both cases if the file does not exist, it will be created instead. Only on ">>" will the information be concatenated if you run it again on the same file. With ">" you would simply overwrite everything you did on the first run.

But here is the deal when using the same input file as the output file. In that particular case, if you use ">" you would be removing the information the "input" part needs to parse, since the output file would be "overwriting it". So in:

```
rev file.txt | cat > file.txt
```

What is actually happening in "slow motion explanation" is:

1. `rev` prepares to reverse the content of `file.txt` and send it to pipe
2. While `rev` is sending the information to pipe, pipe streams it directly to `cat`.
3. While `cat` is receiving the information it will automatically apply it to the `file.txt` it was set with.
4. The keyword here is "while", because everything is happening at the same time. Please see the excellent comments below by Emil to have a deeper understanding on this part.
5. `cat` will not wait for `rev` to pipe the whole file. It will simply start the minute the first part of the information gets to it, which means, depending on what symbol you used, it will open a connection to `file.txt`.
6. In this case since you used the **>** instead of **>>**, the shell will truncate the output file which means it will open **and clear** the information of `file.txt` while waiting for the new information to get to it. With **>>** it would open a connection with `file.txt` and wait for new information on the last line detected.
7. Since the information was already cleared in `file.txt` with **>**, `rev` would try to do it's work and get nothing because `cat` deleted everything in preparation for the new information.

So why do the others work after reading the above. Because of this:

```
rev file.txt | cat > file2.txt && mv file.txt file2.txt
```

Here you are piping to cat which is sending the information to **another** file. In this case, the processed input file `file.txt` is not the same as the output file `file2.txt`. After that you are literally overwriting the whole `file2.txt` with `file.txt`, so all the process made by `cat` was deleted. Basically the whole line could be simplified like `cp file.txt file2.txt` because it is doing the same thing since `file2.txt` at the end looses the `rev` and is overwritten with the `mv` command.

```
rev file.txt | cat >> file.txt
```

In this case you are **concatenating** the information to the same file. So it is only opening a connection to that file but not erasing the information as seen with a single **>**. The end result should be, the original information plus the reversed information.

Comment: The file is not truncated by cat. It is truncated by the shell, *before* any of the commands in the pipeline are even started.

Comment: Correct, was looking for easier words to explain. Since it is a bit hard to explain if the OP does not know what a shell it and all that. Trying to make it as "friendly" as possible.

Comment: Well, it doesn’t really matter that it is done by the shell, but that the timing you present is wrong. The truncation will not happen in step 6, but in step 0. `rev file.txt | cat --bogus-option > file.txt` will also truncate the file, even though cat will not attempt to open it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are correct. Still users that do not know how it behaves will have it easier if we go step by step with only the commands. Also your example is still sending the information to the same file, so bash will read that whole line, see the output and still open AND truncate it. The error is simply the stderr outputting to stdout.

Comment: See also [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), a fantastic collection of tools (available from the package repository as `moreutils`) which includes `sponge`, a tool specifically designed for the usecase of overwriting an input file. For example, the `rev file.txt >file2.txt && mv file2.txt file.txt` workaround would become `rev file.txt | sponge file.txt`, which will work correctly even when there is already something named `file2.txt`.

Comment: @DanielWagner wow that's awesome set of tools.

Answer (score 9):

When the shell sees redirection, it opens the relevant files first, before executing any of the commands involved. Thus, when you do:

```
foo file.txt | bar > file.txt
```

The redirection to `file.txt` causes it to be truncated *before* `foo` is run and can read `file.txt`. On a side note, this is why you cannot do:

```
sed 'blah' file.txt > file.txt
```

And why `sed` has an in-place editing option.

Lastly, doing:

```
.. | cat > file.txt
```

is [a useless use of cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), especially so if you are attempting to read from `file.txt` earlier on.

If you want to reverse a file in-place, [there are no shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file). You might be able to use the `sed` or `awk` tricks with in-place editing.

Answer (score 3):

**`>`** is a redirector (operator) sending the output to something else
(input of next command, printer..)

In your case the output goes to a file `file.txt`, if this file already exist it is overwritten, if not it is created.

**`>>`** is an append operator, if `file.txt` already exist the output is appended to the end of the file. if the file doesn't exist it is created, and the output written to the new file, same as **`>`** (redirector).

Comment: The OP seems to have understood this. The confusion seems to stem only from the same file being on both sides of the `>` and `>>` operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%!rev' -cx file.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` run command
3. `x` save and close